# Entendendo o algoritmo quick sort graficamente

Tags: c, classificação, estrutura-de-dados, quicksort

Tenho esse código abaixo funcionando corretamente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void quicksort (int *vetor, int inicio, int fim) {

int i, j, meio, aux;

i = inicio;
j = fim;
meio = vetor [(inicio+fim)/2];

do {

    while (vetor [i] < meio)
        i++;

    while (vetor [j] > meio)
        j--;

    if (i<= j) {
        aux = vetor[i];
        vetor[i] = vetor[j];
        vetor[j] = aux;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
} while (i <= j);

if (inicio < j)
    quicksort(vetor, inicio, j);
if (i < fim)
    quicksort(vetor, i, fim);
}

int main()
{
int vetor[8] = {25, 57, 48, 37, 12, 92, 86, 33};
int n = 8, i;

quicksort(vetor,0,n-1);

for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
    printf("%d ", vetor[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

1 - Eu determino meio do vetor e esse meio vai ser o pivô, que nas minhas contas é na posição 3, conteúdo 37.

A partir daí qual o próximo passo?

Comment: Talvez isso te ajude: https://youtu.be/ywWBy6J5gz8

Comment: Animações: [wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Sorting_quicksort_anim.gif), [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/images/quick_sort_partition_animation.gif), [wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Quicksort-example.gif).